# Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I'm having a serious issue that makes my computer to wake up automatically without any keyboard or mouse click, it stays in sleep mode about 8 seconds.

**Edit**: It happens randomly, sometimes it just doesn't wake up and works properly, I can't find a constant way of reproducing it.

Is this possible to fix it? If not then how can i make my laptop to hibernate when i close the cover?

I'm using hp pavilion dv6 notebook with additional broadcom wireless and nvidia drivers if it helps.

---

**Edit**:

Here are some info about my /proc/acpi/wakeup;

```
nx1337@nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
P0P3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled
P0P1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
CIR0      S5    *enabled   pnp:00:00
PS2K      S3    *enabled   pnp:00:07
PS2M      S3    *disabled  pnp:00:08
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB1      S3    *disabled
USB2      S3    *disabled
USB3      S3    *disabled
USB4      S3    *disabled
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
USB5      S3    *disabled
USB6      S3    *disabled
USB7      S3    *disabled
HDEF      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
RP02      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
PXSX      S5    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
RP03      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
RP08      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.7
```

I'm afraid I don't even have a PBTN entry so I don't want to mess up my system making wild guesses and disabling things I don't know -what if one of them refers to my power button?

Here is some relevant info from my var/log/syslog;

```
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.383024] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.452554] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.452826] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.454994] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.456292] PM: Entering mem sleep
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.456339] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.456695] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.456746] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.553531] i8042 aux 00:08: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.553549] i8042 kbd 00:07: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8587.553575] ene_ir 00:00: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.049478] PM: suspend of devices complete after 593.170 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.049702] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.220 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.050173] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.081795] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.097841] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.113370] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 63.685 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.113512] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.117408] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.117809] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.221247] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.325216] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.325895] Broke affinity for irq 21
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.325908] Broke affinity for irq 42
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.580520] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.581674] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.581741] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.582259] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.582310] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.582311] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.595760] CPU1 is up
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.595785] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.609304] CPU2 is up
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.609328] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x5
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.622906] CPU3 is up
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.625304] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.646462] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.678443] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.790598] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 157.634 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.790762] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.124 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.790996] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.794640] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.839338] ene_ir 00:00: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8588.839627] i8042 kbd 00:07: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.006396] usb 2-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.122299] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.122359] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.130310] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.192118] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8589.350171] firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: rediscovered device fw0
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.473567] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.479306] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.493692] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.510980] ERROR @wl_wowl_ind_wake_reason : Unable to get wake reason, err = -95
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514192] PM: resume of devices complete after 2724.270 msecs
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514478] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514752] firewire_ohci 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514779] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.1: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514803] pci 0000:04:00.2: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514827] jmb38x_ms 0000:04:00.3: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514851] pci 0000:04:00.4: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514960] r8169 0000:03:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.515128] firewire_ohci 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.515153] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.1: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.515177] pci 0000:04:00.2: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.515215] jmb38x_ms 0000:04:00.3: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.515240] pci 0000:04:00.4: no hotplug settings from platform
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.514480] Restarting tasks ... done.
Mar 18 23:42:27 nx-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC kernel: [ 8591.598871] video LNXVIDEO:02: Restoring backlight state
```

Comment: check /var/log/syslog a post here relevant entries (probably it will be a traceback)

Comment: I'm going to do that as soon as i have access to my laptop...

Comment: I added /var/sys/syslog and /proc/acpi/wakeup info

Answer (score 19):

I had a very similar problem; I will show you an example but you will need to adapt it to your computer. The output here is from my desktop (and trimmed down), so apply *cum grano salis*.

Check the wakeup events for your PC:

```
2& [romano:~/etc] % cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PCI0      S4    *disabled  no-bus:pci0000:00
COM1      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:06
PEGH      S4    *disabled
PEGL      S4    *disabled
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
PCX1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PCX5      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PCX7      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.6
HUB       S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
EUS1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EUS2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
PBTN      S4    *enabled
```

The `enabled` events are the one that can wake up your computer. One of these is firing up in your case; you have to discover which one.

You can toggle the wakeup status on, for example, `EUS1` (whatever it means --- no idea)  with the command:

```
echo EUS1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

and then you can check that the wakeup is disabled, by repeating the first command. Now you can try to suspend and see if the PC stays suspended or not. Repeat.

**Do not** disable the event on `PBTN` --- it is the power button. You can be unable to resume in that case!

My strategy is normally to disable everything minus the `PBTN` --- now the resume should be trigger *only* with the power button. You can then try to reenable other sources (or not).

Once you have found the culprit(s) event(s), you can add them to your `/etc/rc.local` to make the change permanent. Notice however that the interface is really badly thought, and you can only *toggle* the status of enabled/disabled, not set it; so for example to disable the EUS1 independently on its status you should use

```
grep 'EUS1.*enabled' < /proc/acpi/wakeup >/dev/null && echo "EUS1" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

in your `/etc/rc.local`.

In my case the culprit where EHC y XHC devices, probably because I have an USB keyboard (not sure though), this is en excerpt of my `rc.local`:

```
for device in XHC EHC1 EHC2; do
    grep $device /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled > /dev/null && {
        echo Disabling wakeup on $device 
        echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    }
done
```

Comment: I know it's been a while since you answered and I'm posting it for notification, could you please look at my edited question because I'm clueless what to do...

Comment: Added a bit to the answer. I would try --- a laptop that can't send is useless, and the worst thing that can happen is that you need a hard reset... But no guarantees implied.

Comment: @Rmano can you please have look at my scenario on `http://askubuntu.com/questions/852600/ubuntu-16-04-wakes-up-immediately-from-suspend-after-installing-fprint-in-lenovo` and help me to figure it out

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya --- I would try to disable one at a time (minus LID, which is probably the one you want) and check.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you very much, by disabling `IGBE` the system suspended properly, by the way what is actually `IGBE`?. In the process I have disable 3 other options, how do I get them back enabled again

Comment: About the first one: only the BIOS writer and the motherboard manufacturer know, look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236127/acpi-wakeup-4-letters-code-meaning . For the second one: it's a toggle, if you do the `echo` thing again you'll reenable it. (You probably need to do that at every reboot, as I explained here in the answer).

Comment: Just an update... `PBTN` no longer appears in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. So no danger of disabling the power button anymore.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I'm running `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"` and in my install, i still see `PBTN`. This is on a Dell m6700 Precision.

Comment: Any idea why `tee` is required here instead of the simpler `echo EUS1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup`?

Comment: @Norman is because you need to do the write as root, with `sudo`. But obviously, that are other ways to do it.

Comment: @Rmano I'm running in a shell launched with `sudo`.

Comment: @NormanRamsey in that case there's no difference (living dangerously, eh? ;-))

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 on a 2013 Macbook Pro. For me it is the LID0 device which I need to disable