# Xubuntu after suspend turns back on

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

I am currently using Xubuntu, apparently every time I try to suspend the computer, it turns right back on... Any ideas?

Comment: Is this similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep ? I have put an answer there, try to a) go through this steps and/or b) add info to your question, look at that one for an hint.