# 14.04.3 wakes up as soon as putting to sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management

I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 32 bit OS. I set my comp to sleep after 5 minutes of idleness. It was running OK until today. I should say that handling of power management is not reliable in Ubuntu. My system is up-to-date.

I also tried it in shell like

```
 sudo pm-suspend
```

the result is the same, it wakes up immediately.

I let kids use my comp, they might change some settings unintentially?

How can I know what the problem is?

EDIT: Here is output of `dmesg` relating to power management:

```
  [ 2463.965022] CPU1 is up
  [ 2463.966158] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
  [ 2463.971671] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2463.971713] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2463.972208] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2463.972239] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2463.972284] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2463.988468] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 16.985 msecs
  [ 2463.988985] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.487 msecs
  [ 2463.992121] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
  [ 2463.992175] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
  [ 2463.992426] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
  [ 2463.992532] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
  [ 2463.992582] usb usb7: root hub lost power or was reset
  [ 2463.992714] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2464.027300] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
  [ 2464.133550] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
  [ 2464.352083] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
  [ 2464.360273] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
  [ 2464.492085] usb 6-1: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
  [ 2464.831680] PM: resume of devices complete after 842.689 msecs
  [ 2464.832214] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

And here is output of cat /proc/acpi/wakeup:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
UHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
UHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.1
UHC3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.2
UHC4      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
UHC5      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.1
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.7
EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.7
PXS1      S4    *disabled
EXP3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
EXP5      S4    *disabled
EXP6      S4    *disabled
AZAL      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
MODM      S4    *disabled
```

I am currently trying suggestions in this link [Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep/598258#598258)

EDIT2: Here is output of /var/log/pm-suspend.log

```
 Mon Aug 24 17:34:15 EEST 2015: performing suspend
 /etc/uswsusp.conf: Could not stat configuration file
 KMS graphics driver is in use, skipping quirks.
 Mon Aug 24 17:34:25 EEST 2015: Awake.
 Mon Aug 24 17:34:25 EEST 2015: Running hooks for resume
 Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
 /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: disabled.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

 /dev/sda:
  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
  APM_level = 254
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
 Reloaded unloaded modules.
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
 Selected interface 'wlan0'
 OK
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd resume suspend:
 Unable to connect to wicd daemon - is it running?
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55wicd resume suspend: disabled.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd resume suspend:
 /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
 /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/00CPU resume suspend:
 /etc/pm/sleep.d/00CPU resume suspend: not executable.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

 Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
 /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

 Mon Aug 24 17:34:25 EEST 2015: Finished.
```

Comment: You can try http://askubuntu.com/a/598258/16395 --- sometime it works. Worked for me. (if you post make and model of your "comp" it may help). (and yes, linux must reverse enginner bios and motherboard hacks --- ask your notebook maker, whom you voted with your wallet, to better support linux)

Comment: I had a problem like this. I would get the lockscreen instead of sleep. I forget what I did, but I know it had something to do with running programs interrupting sleep. Check `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` to see if there's anything that could be interrupting sleep. Also paste the contents into your question so we can see.

Comment: @Zacharee1  
Thank you for the tip, I posted last part of the log file. I did played settings of  `/proc/acpi/wakeup` in the past but it was OK until today.

Comment: Do you have user suspend installed? (The first error comes from the package `uswsusp`, that I think it's long deprecated...?)

Comment: Yeah. There's definitely something going on with the `/etc/uswsusp.conf` file. It's probably corrupt, which means running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure uswsusp` _might_ work. I don't know whether it's a package name or not.

Comment: @Rmano 
Do you think I have conflicting power managers installed? I have following tools installed related to `suspend` I typed in synaptic  `acpi, acpi-support, acpitool, hibernate, pm-utils, powernap, qshutdown, upower, uswsusp`

Comment: I do not have my laptop handy now --- never installed anything special to have suspend/resume working. If you have manually installed all that tools, yes, my guess is that you have a configuration mess going on.  On my desktop I have just `acpi-support` and `upower` installed of your list (I *think* I have `pm-utils` in the laptop, will check when I can). Unfortunately, going back after manual install of conflicting packages is not straightforward (sometime not even possible), so it can be messy...