# Ubuntu 14.04 sometimes does not suspend when laptop lid closed

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management, lts

Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Set to suspend when lid closed.

Mostly it works - often I can use it for a week, suspending and resuming with no problems.  But sometimes *something* changes and it stops working: shutting the lid will do nothing - the machine keeps running.

If the fan comes on then I know it has happened.  Otherwise the first I know about it is when I open it the next day and the battery is completely flat, or if I open the lid a short while later and notice it's still running.

Rebooting always solves it - meaning that it will now suspend and resume happily again - but I have not found any less severe way to recover the situation.  I also don't know what to do to force the problem.

I have found many questions about suspend not working at all - but that's not the problem here.

Is there anything I can do to diagnose please?

Comment: This solution seemed to work for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep Thanks! n.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue.
I didn't identify the source yet, but here's what I did

1-Ran `dmesg` and captured the time of the last event.
2-Ran `dmesg | grep "{last event time}" -A1000` to capture the lines. You should get only 1 line.
3-Closed the lid.

In my case, it tries to suspend, and it wakes up itself almost immediately.

4-Opened the lid, unlocked the screen and ran again the last dmesg with the grep.

I saw in the output the computer is going to sleep, and immediately wakes up itself, on it's own.

I guess there's something like laptop-tools or similar waking it up. I removed the USB devices as well, and it keeps waking up.

I will let you know if I manage to find the solution. I'm using a Thinkpad T430S here.

Best!

Comment: Thanks - that's a good suggestion, although I don't see the problem any more: a month or two ago the kernel updated to the 16.04LTS kernel and the problem hasn't happened since.