# Acer Acer SF114-34 wakeup immediately after suspend // 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and 22.04 LTS

Tags: suspend, power-management, acer

after i added an mSATA i have the problem, that my Acer SF114-34 would not go to standby. before it worked perfectly...

I already

- Manipulate /etc/systemd/logind.conf
  HandleSuspendKey=suspend
  HandleLidSwitch=suspend
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
- Already activated "suspend after closed lid" in Gnome-Tweak-Tool
- In Bios S3 is active. I never change these setting.
- The new mSATA is encrypted with Luks

Command: journalctl| grep suspend

> Nov 08 17:20:57 cthulhu systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service:
> Succeeded. Nov 08 17:22:55 cthulhu ModemManager[1079]: 
> [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend Nov 08 17:23:00 cthulhu
> kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep) Nov 08 17:23:02 cthulhu kernel:
> printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug) Nov 08
> 17:23:03 cthulhu kernel: PM: suspend exit Nov 08 17:23:03 cthulhu
> systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded. Nov 08 18:41:28
> cthulhu ModemManager[1066]:   [sleep-monitor] system is about to
> suspend Nov 08 18:41:33 cthulhu kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep) Nov
> 08 18:41:35 cthulhu kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use
> no_console_suspend to debug) Nov 08 18:41:36 cthulhu kernel: PM:
> suspend exit Nov 08 18:41:36 cthulhu systemd[1]:
> systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> ModemManager[1066]:   [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
> Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate
> operation is not supported, using regular suspend instead. Nov 08
> 18:47:31 cthulhu systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation
> is not supported, using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31
> cthulhu systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not
> supported, using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:31 cthulhu
> systemd-logind[1005]: Requested hibernate operation is not supported,
> using regular suspend instead. Nov 08 18:47:36 cthulhu kernel: PM:
> suspend entry (deep) Nov 08 18:47:38 cthulhu kernel: printk:
> Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug) Nov 08
> 18:47:39 cthulhu kernel: PM: suspend exit Nov 08 18:47:39 cthulhu
> systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.

Do you have any idea to fix that?
Thank's and
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out the error. The problem was that the new mssd I had installed did not go into sleep mode. As a workaround this helped me -> [Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230534)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the link ([Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)) packaged as a quote. This serves as a copy.

> Check the wakeup events for your PC:
>
> ```
> 2& [romano:~/etc] % cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 
> Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
> PCI0      S4    *disabled  no-bus:pci0000:00
> COM1      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:06
> PEGH      S4    *disabled
> PEGL      S4    *disabled
> IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
> PCX1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
> PCX5      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
> PCX7      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.6
> HUB       S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
> EUS1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
> EUS2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
> PBTN      S4    *enabled
> ```
>
> The enabled events are the one that can wake up your computer. One of
> these is firing up in your case; you have to discover which one.
>
> You can toggle the wakeup status on, for example, EUS1 (whatever it
> means --- no idea) with the command:
>
> ```
> echo EUS1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
> ```
>
> and then you can check that the wakeup is disabled, by repeating the
> first command. Now you can try to suspend and see if the PC stays
> suspended or not. Repeat.
>
> Do not disable the event on PBTN --- it is the power button. You can
> be unable to resume in that case!
>
> My strategy is normally to disable everything minus the PBTN --- now
> the resume should be trigger only with the power button. You can then
> try to reenable other sources (or not).
>
> Once you have found the culprit(s) event(s), you can add them to your
> /etc/rc.local to make the change permanent. Notice however that the
> interface is really badly thought, and you can only toggle the status
> of enabled/disabled, not set it; so for example to disable the EUS1
> independently on its status you should use
>
> ```
> grep 'EUS1.*enabled' < /proc/acpi/wakeup >/dev/null && echo "EUS1" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
> ```
>
> in your /etc/rc.local.
>
> In my case the culprit where EHC y XHC devices, probably because I
> have an USB keyboard (not sure though), this is en excerpt of my
> rc.local:
>
> ```
> for device in XHC EHC1 EHC2; do
>     grep $device /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled > /dev/null && {
>         echo Disabling wakeup on $device 
>         echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
>     }
> done
> ```